# Переключение между лицевой и обратной стороной визитки

Tags: xml, svg, html, ui, javascript

При загрузке [страницы](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html) отображается "Лицевая сторона" визитки (по-умолчанию). Она генерируется вот такой разметкой:

```
<div id="SVG_canvas" width="93mm" height="53mm">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="93mm" height="53mm">
        <color-profile name="acmecmyk" xlink:href="http://printers.example.com/acmecorp/model1234" />
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="none" fill-opacity="0.0" />
        <g id="square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px" rx="8" ry="8" id="myRect" class="chart" />
        </g>
        <use xlink:href="#square" transform="scale(2)" />
        <text x="20" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="43pt" id="hello">Hello World!</text>
        <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="25px" fill="#FF0000">Кукарамба</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Обратная сторона" визитки, на той же [странице](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html), должен отображаться другой div:

```
<div id="SVG_canvas1" width="93mm" height="53mm">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
width="93mm" height="53mm">
    <color-profile name="acmecmyk" xlink:href="http://printers.example.com/acmecorp/model1234" />
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="none" fill-opacity="0.0" />
    <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="25px" fill="#FF0000">Кукарамба</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

И есть две кнопки - "Лицевая сторона" и "Обратная сторона", которые позволяют переключатся между этими div'ами:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="front" class="btn btn-warning">Лицевая сторона</button>
    <button id="rear" class="btn btn-warning">Обратная сторона</button>
</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне это реализовать? То есть нужно какое-то решение, похожее на табы, но табы здесь не подойдут, нужно именно кнопками переключать SVG холсты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не брезгуете jquery то попробуйте [сделать так](http://jsfiddle.net/chad_888/st5QB/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SVG_canvas1').hide();
    $("#front").click(function () {
        $('#SVG_canvas1').hide();
        $('#SVG_canvas').show();
    });
    $("#rear").click(function () {
        $('#SVG_canvas').hide();
        $('#SVG_canvas1').show();
    });
});​
```

-

```
<div id="SVG_canvas" width="93mm" height="53mm">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="93mm" height="53mm">
        <color-profile name="acmecmyk" xlink:href="http://printers.example.com/acmecorp/model1234" />
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px"
        fill="none" fill-opacity="0.0" />
        <g id="square">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px"
            rx="8" ry="8" id="myRect" class="chart" />
        </g>
        <use xlink:href="#square" transform="scale(2)" />
        <text x="20" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="43pt" id="hello">Hello World!</text>
        <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="25px"
        fill="#FF0000">Кукарамба</text>
    </svg>
</div>
<div id="SVG_canvas1" width="93mm" height="53mm">
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
    <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    width="93mm" height="53mm">
        <color-profile name="acmecmyk" xlink:href="http://printers.example.com/acmecorp/model1234" />
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px"
        fill="none" fill-opacity="0.0" />
        <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="25px" fill="#FF0000">Кукарамба</text>
    </svg>
</div>
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="front" class="btn btn-warning">Лицевая сторона</button>
    <button id="rear" class="btn btn-warning">Обратная сторона</button>
</div>​
```

Comment: Конечно, не брезгую, огромное спасибо!